# Missing sudo password error when running ansible from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible

The command is the command jenkins runs to run the yml file

```
devops18@devops-vbox:/usr/share/ansible/roles/webrole$ /usr/bin/ansible-playbook /usr/share/ansible/roles/webrole/web.yml -i /usr/share/ansible/ansiserver -f 5

PLAY [ubuntuclient] **************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ubuntuclient]

TASK [webrole : Install JDK on Ubuntu] *******************************************************************************************************
fatal: [ubuntuclient]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************
ubuntuclient               : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

devops18@devops-vbox:/usr/share/ansible/roles/webrole$
```

Please suggest any changes I need to make in jenkins job configure to make it work

Answer (score 1):

You need to prompt for password with `-kK` when calling playbook:

```
/usr/bin/ansible-playbook /usr/share/ansible/roles/webrole/web.yml -i /usr/share/ansible/ansiserver -f 5 -kK
```

or add pwd in `--extra-vars` (not recommending)

```
/usr/bin/ansible-playbook /usr/share/ansible/roles/webrole/web.yml -i /usr/share/ansible/ansiserver --extra-vars "ansible_sudo_pass=xxxxxx" -f 5
```

or you can edit `/etc/sudoers`:

```
ubuntuclient        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: I cannot edit the command jenkins uses to invoke the playbook. I tried the third one, giving the same missing sudo password error.